# VSC platform-specific settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My `settings.json` on Linux machine contains setting lines for `cortex-debug` extension:

```
    "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath": "/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/",
    "cortex-debug.JLinkGDBServerPath": "/opt/SEGGER/JLink_V754b/JLinkGDBServerCLExe",
```

The same file on Windows machine should refer to a different file name `JLinkGDBServerCL.exe` (yes, I understand such dumb naming is guilty of Segger, but...)

When settings sync turned on, I continuously get the wrong config on one (Windows or Linux) machine.

Is it possible to set a platform-specific section in `settings.json` to define a different key for an extension?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use VSCode's features to define machine specific settings or prevent certain settings from being synced,

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_configuring-synced-data

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found another solution for my problem.

At first, install `platform-settings` from marketplace:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=runarsf.platform-settings

Next, move required settings to a new place:

```json
"platformSettings.platforms": {
    "win32": {
        "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNUARM/bin/",
        "cortex-debug.JLinkGDBServerPath": "JLinkGDBServerCL.Exe",
    },
    "linux": {
        "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath": "/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/",
        "cortex-debug.JLinkGDBServerPath": "/opt/SEGGER/JLink_V754b/JLinkGDBServerCLExe"
    }
}
```

But variant with sync prevention looks pretty good.